# Frequency-averaged (gray) radiative transfer

Tags: astrophysics, radiation, thermal-radiation, frequency

The equation for radiative transfer is
$$
\omega \cdot \nabla I = \kappa(B - I)
$$
where $I$ is the intensity of radiation, $\omega$ is the ray direction, $\kappa$ the absorption coefficient, $B$ the [Planck function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law). Here, $\kappa=\kappa(\nu)$ (i.e., it depends on the radiation frequency $\nu$).

Often, though, the [gray model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_atmosphere), where $\kappa$ doesn't depend on $\nu$, is used. How can this be justified? What assumptions are used to obtain the gray model from the non-gray model?

Comment: I've modified your question to be more clear in hopes to reopen it. I believe that I kept the intent of your question in tact, but please check this so that we are answering the question you want answered.

Answer (score 2):

The gray model results from starting with the assumption that we have a plane-parallel slab:

[image]

The light ray from the source (i.e., the star's atmosphere) travels at some angle, $\theta$, from normal, $z=0$. Since the light is coming from an angle, we need to account for that by modifying the radiative transfer equation to have a *vertical* [optical depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth), defined by
$$
\tau_{\lambda,v}(z)=\int_z^0\kappa_\lambda\rho\,dz
$$
which gives us
$$
\omega\frac{dI_\lambda}{d\tau_{\lambda,v}}=I_\lambda-B_\lambda
$$
with $\omega=\cos\theta$. Since the path length of the ray does not offer a unique geometric depth of the atmosphere, we cannot use $\nabla I$ and must use the above form for the radiative transfer equation.

In most stellar atmospheres, the **primary source of opacity is the photoionization of H$^-$ ions**. Fortunately, **the opacity from photoionzation of hydrogen ions does not vary rapidly with wavelength**, so we can approximate the opacity as
$$
\kappa_\lambda\approx \bar\kappa
$$
where $\bar\kappa$ is some average opacity, usually the [Rosseland mean opacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opacity_(optics)#Planck_and_Rosseland_opacity).

Comment: How to justify the using of the gray model if, for example, some combustion system is considered but not atmosphere processes?
The absorption coefficient may oscillate among spectral lines.

Comment: If the opacity does vary a lot with wavelength, then you cannot use the gray model as an accurate representation. I would think, though, that it still would be good for a first-order model.